# Bootstrap Input Group from 3 elements, when textBox is first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create search control with Filter (drop-down), but i can't make it beautiful.

http://jsfiddle.net/d2L9afh3/1/ Here is example - mine drop-down and other controls doesn't look as altogether.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="input-group">       
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term..."/>
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please have a look at the demo, Hope it helps you

http://jsfiddle.net/d2L9afh3/4/

CSS:

```
.search-panel .btn{border-radius:0; border-left:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the bootstrap scripts too ?

Comment: I tought you had problems in your html file. If I run your example it looks ok ... it is altogether ...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/g7WEbEH.png here dropdown has rounded corners, that why i wrote not altogether. I want that dropdown will be joined with input like here : http://jsfiddle.net/d2L9afh3/3/ (3rd example)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i do not know why it does that (maybe because it is a button and it is defined with rounded corners) ... but you can overwrite it :

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle corners" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

> css:

```
.corners
{
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;

   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```